# Validating ASP.Net Custom MembershipUser over WCF Causing Unsolicited Service Calls?

Tags: wcf, asp.net-membership, membership-provider

Okay,...first the facts.

I'm working on an ASP.Net project which validates it's users across a WCF service.  I have a `CutomMembershipUser` class in a shared assembly which inherits from MembershipUser since I'm using a custom membership provider.  All this cannot change because it's out of my remit.

Here's roughly what's happening. I've got some code in the Logged_In event of a login control that looks like this...

```
            CustomMembershipUser user = (CustomMembershipUser)SecurityBL.GetUser(userName);

            if (user.Customer.ToLower() == "some user")
            {
                //impl omitted
            }
```

The first line executes without problems and I get the correct user back from the service.  However, in the second line, when I compare the `user.Customer` property a second request is sent to the service with an empty `userName` string which hangs the whole IDE for about 30 secnods or so and eventually throws a `FaultException<T>` which I can catch on the service side.

Obviously my first assumption was that there was some logic in the getter of that property that lazy loads the property but there isn't; in fact it's an auto implemented property!

Even more strange than that,..in the calling code I can't even catch the exception which tells me that the request is coming from a different thread than that which I'm executing.

This same problem happens for **any** property access on this object whether it's overridden or entirely new.

Has anyone seen anything like this before?  I'v been scratching my head for 2 days now and I'm not sure what to try next.

**Any** help would be great.

Thanks in advance.
Stimul8d

Comment: Can you post information with the type of binding you're using and one of the auto-generated properties (unless you mean auto-implemented properties -- e.g., get;set;)?  Are you able to watch the second call with a tool like fiddler to see what's being called and what's being sent to the service?  It's a strange issue, and I may be reaching here.

Comment: lol.  I've been reaching for a while now.  I'm using BasicHttpBinding so no voodoo going on it would seem.  If I'm being honest I don't even see the first request go off in Fiddler but I think that's down to the object requesting the data being held locally in a dll and plugged into the Membership API since I can see "normal" service requests fire off fine.  Does the Membership stuff do any proxying or event subscription behind the scenes that I don't know of ???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

membership is pretty straight ahead and actually has no knowledge of network communications especially not WCF,, so there has to be something hinky happening in *your* code. really.

if you want to try and isolate the smallest footprint of code that reproduces the effect and upload it somewhere I would be happy to take a look.

Comment: After much deliberation I would agree,..something is definitely askew with our code but I haven't even been able to faithfully replicate the issue in isolation yet.  I think this is going to be a real headache until we can do that but thanks for the help all the same. big tick for you.

Comment: @stim - good luck. just add another comment if you want to revisit this.